# Android firebase create and display username

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase user sign up method with email and password. While creating a new user I also store information such username that later on needs to be displayed in app profile page.

How could I retrieve the username of currently logged in person ?

Thank you in advance

[image]

```
private void registration(){

    final String email = Email.getText().toString().toString().trim();
    final String password = Password.getText().toString().trim();
    final String username = Username.getText().toString().trim();
    final String age = Age.getText().toString().trim();
    final String userID = userAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(username)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(age)){

        showProgress.setMessage("Registration in progress...");
        showProgress.show();

        userAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                    String user_id = userAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    DatabaseReference current_user_db = DatbaseOfUsers.child(user_id);
                    current_user_db.child("email").setValue(email);
                    current_user_db.child("username").setValue(username);
                    current_user_db.child("Age").setValue(age);
                    current_user_db.child("uID").setValue(userID);

                    showProgress.dismiss();

                    //After user is created main screen intent is called
                    Intent mainpage = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainPageActivity.class);
                    mainpage.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(mainpage);
                }

                else if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                    showProgress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Error While Register",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        });

    }

    else{
        showProgress.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Please Enter All Required Fields",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final FirebaseUser Theuser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
      if (Theuser !=null)
    _UID = Theuser.getUid();
```

Comment: Is not going to return just a user ID ?

Answer (score 0):

You can send request to `Users` with current user's uid.

```
FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); 

mDatabase.child("Users").orderByChild(currentUser.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

In `onDataChange` returns value you are looking as `dataSnapshot`. Then cast it to your model, get the want ever you want.